# How to make an extension method not using the parameter?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Im trying to create such and extension method:

```
public static DateTime HistoryFrom(this DateTime dateTime){
return new DateTime(1900,1,1);
}
```

but this does not work, probably beacuse of the never used parameter.
Is there any way how to make this as an extension to DateTime structure?

thanks

Comment: How are you trying to use that?

Comment: _this does not work_ please explain what doesn't work.

Comment: Is this a compilation error, or a runtime error?

Comment: I cant reach the method in code, it is not in intellisense a when I type it by hand, it causes an error

Comment: This code should work fine. And a parameter you never use doesn't cause any problem.

Comment: Have you imported the right namespace?

Comment: yes, namespaces are imported; this is the code I call : var date = DateTime.HistoryFrom(); , is that right?

Comment: and this is the error : Error 26 'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'HistoryFrom'

Comment: Extension methods works on instances of a class, not directly on the class name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use like so:

```
var history = new DateTime().HistoryFrom();
```

But that is pointless creating a `DateTime` you are not using.

Without changing the Extensions class:

```
var history = YourExtensionClass.HistoryFrom(null);
```

or:

```
var history = ((DateTime)null).HistoryFrom();
```

Or remove the `this` parameter altogether if you don't want it, then you won't need to pass `null`.